# Internal network adapters only function when PCMCIA card is inserted otherwise they throw error codes

Tags: windows-10, laptop, network-adapter, toshiba-laptop, pcmcia

I have a laptop, Toshiba Satellite A135-S4427 (Windows 10), that has an internal WiFi adapter and onboard NIC that both stop functioning (Error Codes 10 and 35 appear in Device Manager). If I insert a PCMCIA card the internal adapters both function (no errors whatsoever) but the PCMCIA card doesn't even get power (according to the LED indicators on the PCMCIA card). I've checked the drivers, Windows updates, reinstalled Windows 10 (using the refresh option), did a full teardown to check for physical damage (water, blown caps, etc) with no avail.

Update: I tested a USB bootable version of linux and the network adapters functioned perfectly. So this does appear to be a Windows issue. I also put the HDD into another (slightly newer) laptop and networking functioned. I also replaced the wireless NIC with a new WNIC and that experienced the same issue.

Update: I have installed a new HDD and installed Windows 10 (clean) and the issue is still occuring.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!